# Old Sears Paint Sprayer In-line Switch Question

Tags: switches, toggle-switch

I have an old Sears paint sprayer compressor my late father gave me.  It's model number 106.151210.  According to the data plate, its 115V, 7 amps.  It was sitting in the garage and one of my children or my spouse either ran over or stepped on the plastic in-line on/off toggle switch and crushed it beyond repair.  The switch was a Leviton 12A-125V switch that was original to the sprayer.  Up until the switch was destroyed, it worked great at pumping up bike tires, mower tires, etc. and I'd like to fix it since my dad gave it to me.  Replacing the switch doesn't seem too hard, but I am having a lot of difficulty finding an in-line toggle switch to replace it with that appears to be an equivalent switch.  Everything seems to either be a 3A or 6A 125V in-line switch.  Do they even make 12A-125V in-line toggle switches anymore, and if so, where can I get one?  I can't seem to find one online or at the big box stores.  As an alternative, would the 6A 125V work?

Comment: Use the words "heavy duty" in your search. https://smile.amazon.com/Heavy-Inline-Switch-Current-Rocker/dp/B07XK9YXJV/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=heavy+duty+inline+toggle+switch&qid=1588645485&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t been able to find an in-line 125VAC 12A switch but there are 125VAC 12A switches which are a bit pricey  (at least what I consider pricey). On DigiKey.com you can search for switches. Here is one example: GTB-2B12 , 12A, 125VAC, https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cw-industries/GTB-2B12/CW202-ND/3190599. Note that you’ll probably want to buy a project box to enclose the switch and wiring. There are project boxes on DigiKey.com as well.